# How to get total number of users in each status at End of Day based on event log table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, event-log

I got an event log table which captures the change of status of all users, say status A, status B and Status C. They can change it whenever they want. How can I get the snapshot of how many users are in each status at every End of Day (from the earliest day in the event log table till the latest day)

Appreciate if anyone can show me how to do it by PostsgreSQL in an elegant way. Thanks!

Edit: the event log table captures a bunch of events (one of them is status change) of every user, log_id records the order of the event log of that particular user.

```
 user_id  |     log_time     | status | event_A | log_id |
----------------------------------------------------------
   456    | 2019-01-05 15:00 |   C    |         |   5    |
   123    | 2019-01-05 14:00 |   C    |         |   4    |
   123    | 2019-01-05 13:00 |        |   xxx   |   3    |
   456    | 2019-01-04 22:00 |   B    |         |   4    |
   456    | 2019-01-04 10:00 |   C    |   xxx   |   3    |
   987    | 2019-01-04 05:00 |   C    |         |   3    |
   123    | 2019-01-03 23:00 |   B    |         |   2    |
   987    | 2019-01-03 15:00 |        |   xxx   |   2    |
   456    | 2019-01-02 22:00 |   A    |   xxx   |   2    |
   123    | 2019-01-01 23:00 |   C    |         |   1    |
   456    | 2019-01-01 09:00 |   B    |   xxx   |   1    |
   987    | 2019-01-01 04:00 |   A    |         |   1    |
```

So I want to get the total number of user in each status at End of Day:

```
   Date    | status A | status B | status C |
---------------------------------------------
2019-01-05 |     0    |     0    |     3    |
2019-01-04 |     0    |     2    |     1    |
2019-01-03 |     2    |     1    |     0    |
2019-01-02 |     2    |     0    |     1    |
2019-01-01 |     1    |     1    |     1    |
```

Comment: Assuming Status is the only column that can be updated, adding an "update trigger" that is increasing a counter flag by 1 at somewhere might help solving this. Or, if you need list of people that status is changed, add a flag column to your main table, update its value while updating the status, then return a list of people whose flag is different than default value

Comment: Please include some sample data which would make your question clearer.

Comment: Just added a sample @TimBiegeleisen. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

This was quiet challenging to do :). I tried to fragment the sub-queries for good readability. It is probably not an very efficient way to do what you want, but it does the job.

```
-- collect all days to make sure there are no missing days
WITH all_days_cte(dt) as (
    SELECT
        generate_series(
        (SELECT min(date_trunc('day', log_time)) from your_table),
        (SELECT max(date_trunc('day', log_time)) from your_table),
        '1 day'
        )::DATE
),
-- collect all useres
all_users_cte as (
    select distinct
        user_id
    from your_table
),
-- setup the table with infos needed, i.e. only the last status by day and user_id
infos_to_aggregate_cte as (
    select
        s.user_id,
        s.dt,
        s.status
    from (
        select
            user_id,
            date_trunc('day', log_time)::DATE as dt,
            status,
            row_number() over (partition by user_id, date_trunc('day', log_time) order by log_time desc) rn
        from your_table
        where status is not null
    ) s
-- only the last status of the day
    where s.rn = 1
),
-- now we still have a problem, we need to find the last status, if there was no change on a day
completed_infos_cte as (
    select
        u.user_id,
        d.dt,
        -- not very efficient, but found no other way (first_value(...) would be nice, but there is no simple way to exclude nulls
        (select
            status
        from infos_to_aggregate_cte i2 
        where i2.user_id = u.user_id 
             and i2.dt <= d.dt 
             and i2.status is not null 
        order by i2.dt desc 
        limit 1) status
    from all_days_cte d
    -- cross product for all dates and users (that is what we need for our aggregation)
    cross join all_users_cte u
    left outer join infos_to_aggregate_cte i on u.user_id = i.user_id
        and d.dt = i.dt
)
select
    c.dt,
    sum(case when status = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) status_a,
    sum(case when status = 'B' then 1 else 0 end) status_b,
    sum(case when status = 'C' then 1 else 0 end) status_c    
from completed_infos_cte c
group by c.dt
order by c.dt desc
```